# How can I fix this JMeter LoggerAppender error I'm getting in Windows?

Tags: windows, jmeter

Whenever I run JMeter at the Windows command line, I get this error message.  Everything runs fine, but the error message is distracting.  Can I do something to get rid of it?  I'm using JMeter 5.1.1 r1855137.

```
2019-10-07 09:12:39,625 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class org.jmeterplugins.repository.logging.LoggerAppender for element Logger: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.jmeterplugins.repository.logging.LoggerAppender java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.jmeterplugins.repository.logging.LoggerAppender
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.findFactoryMethod(PluginBuilder.java:235)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:135)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:959)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:899)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:891)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:514)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:238)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:250)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:547)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:619)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:636)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:231)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:153)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:121)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:46)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:383)
        at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.<clinit>(JMeter.java:124)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:251)
```

Comment: Where did you put plugin manager jar?

Comment: @user7294900 I have the JMeterPluginsCMD.bat file in the same folder as my jmeter.bat file

Comment: You need to install plugin manager jar

Comment: @user7294900 I already have a file called "jmeter-plugins-manager-1.3.jar" in my lib/ext folder.  I downloaded it from https://jmeter-plugins.org/install/Install/  Is this the file you mean?  I still get the error

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you're experiencing the consequence of [JMeter enhancement 60589](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60589) which was introduced in [JMeter 3.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-32/), it seems that you have an outdated version of the [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) somewhere in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath).

1. Remove previous version(s) of the JMeter Plugins Manager from "lib/ext" folder of your JMeter installation (same for the plugins, if any). A better idea would be getting a "clean" copy of JMeter from [JMeter Downloads](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)
2. Obtain a [new version](https://jmeter-plugins.org/get/) of the JMeter Plugins Manager and drop it to /lib/ext folder of your JMeter installation
3. Restart JMeter - at this stage you should not see any logging-related errors
4. Install the plugins you need using the Plugins Manager.